# Custom keyboard crashing after trying to set the text input as the title of a label in each key

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I'm trying my hand at making a custom keyboard while learning Swift. In my keyboard, each key is a separate UIView with a UILabel in it. Each UILabel has a tag of 1. At first I coded each key's input manually, but I decided to optimize the code and set a function that takes the UILabel's text and sets it as input but for some reason the keyboard is crashing (no log

**Note 1: One key is shown to simplify things** 
**Note 2: The gesture is defined elsewhere, it'd not causing the crash**

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
var Qkey = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(3, 11, 26, 38))
        var Q = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, 8, 17, 27))
        Q.tag = 1
        Q.text = "Q"
        Qkey.addSubview(Q)
        tapRec1.addTarget(self, action: "keyPressed:")
        Qkey.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec1)
        self.view.addSubview(Qkey)
}

func keyPressed(sender: UIView){
    let theLabel : UILabel! = sender.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel;
    var string = theLabel.text!

    (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText("\(theLabel)")
}
```

Error observed in the log:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer viewWithTag:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x798bba30'
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is for the UIView (sender) on which the function is called on, to grab all the subviews (UILabels) with tag 1, and set their text as the keyboard input. Even doing it on on key crashes:( Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: which line cause crash?

Comment: @Indrajeet this one func keyPressed1(sender: UIView){

        var theLabel : UILabel = sender.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel;
    (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText(theLabel.text!)
   }

Comment: Made theLabel variable implicit optional. It helps you

Comment: @Indrajeet finally got a log and updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Here's the working code:

```
func keyPressed(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    for subview in sender.view!.subviews as [UIView]  {

        if subview.tag == 1
        {
            let label = subview as UILabel
            if capsLockOn {
            (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText("\(label.text!.uppercaseString)")
            } else {
            (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText("\(label.text!.lowercaseString)")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should not be like this

```
func keyPressed(sender: UIView)
{
   let theLabel : UILabel! = sender.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel;
   var string = theLabel.text!

   (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText("\(theLabel)")
}
```

It should be

```
func keyPressed(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let theLabel : UILabel! = sender.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel
    var string = theLabel.text! //No need of this line

     println(theLabel.text) //To test value is coming or not
     (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText(theLabel.text)
}
```

Comment: I just finished fixing my code and it worked :) I'll try your method and see if ti works

Comment: great, can you tell me the solution?

Comment: Yeah sure but I just found a small bug in it if you can help. Any way of contacting you directly? I'll post the solution as soon as it works perfectly

Comment: sorry, i have to leave now